# Advanced HTML form with some JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Imagine that I have a fictional website where a user can sign for some courses. Let's say that there are 3 different kinds of courses: mathematics, languages and biology. User can choose multiple courses in one form.

I would like to have a form where a user chooses if he wants a course from mathematics or languages or biology and then he can choose the one he wants.

User will select what kind of course he wants,

```
<select type="text" name="course">
   <option value="0">mathematics</option>
   <option value="1">languages</option>
   <option value="2">biology</option>
</select>
```

and according to what user selected there would be another select with specific courses of that kind. So if user chooses mathematics, next select would be filled with courses from mathematics

```
<select type="text" name="topic">
   <option value="0">algebra</option>
   <option value="0">calculus</option>
   ...
</select>
```

In the end there would be a button which will recreate this so the user can add as many courses to his application as he wants.

Can you give me any hints how to do this? Or is there some better way, how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Its common referred to as Cascading Dropdowns, google that and you should find heaps of ways to do it

Comment: I would recommend adding a class to each option and displaying each option with the correct class in the secondary select box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pseudo-code / diagram which might help

```
// Display Main Options (Math, Lang, Bio)
<select type="text" name="course">
    <option value="math">mathematics</option>
    <option value="lang">languages</option>
    <option value="bio">biology</option>
</select>

// OnChange of the Main Options, check which option is checked

// Display Secundairy Options menu according to the chosen Main Option
// Note the IDs of these selects and the values of the Main Options
<select type="text" name="subCourse" id="math">
    <option value="SimpleAlg">Simple Algebra</option>
    <option value="AdvAlg">Advanced Algebra</option>
    <option value="xx">...</option>
</select>
// OR
<select type="text" name="subCourse" id="lang">
    <option value="BasEng">Basic English</option>
    <option value="AdvEng">Advanced English</option>
    <option value="xx">...</option>
</select>
// OR
<select type="text" name="subCourse" id="bio">
    <option value="xx">...</option>
</select>

// Display button which adds the selected course to a list
// OnClick on the button, update a shown list of selected courses
<ul id="selectedCourses">
    <li id="BasEng">Basic English [<a onclick="removeCourse()">X</a>]</li>
</ul>
```